# Python ctypes : byref() is not reflecting the updated value

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, pass-by-reference, ctypes

I am writing wrapper for some C API's in python. I am able to write the wrapper and when i am trying to call that wrapper from another program to access the API, the pointer variable changed value is not getting updated in python variable.

My API code from pythonWrapper.py :

```
import ctypes
from enum import Enum

_obj = cdll.LoadLibrary(./sharedObj.so)

#some enums and structure will be here like :

class structwrap(Structure):
  _fields_ = [("id", c_int),
              ("type", c_int),
              ("state", c_int)]
  def __init__(self):
      self.id = 0
      self.type = 0
      self.state = 0


def wrappedAPI(structwrapList, count):
    _obj.wrappedAPI.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(structwrapList),ctypes.POINTER(c_int)]
    _obj.wrappedAPI.restype = int
    if not structwrapList:
        structwrapList = structwrap()
    ret = _obj.orgAPI(byref(structwrapList),byref(c_int(count)))
    print (count)
    return ret
```

The corresponding C code is :

```
typedef struct structOrg
{
    int                 id;     /* index */
    dvDevIcType_t       type;  /* type */
    dvDevExecState_t    state;   /* state */
}structOrg_t;


int orgAPI(structOrg_t *structList, int *count){
...
//count value is being changed here. like count = count+1
}
```

The above python file is being called called from test.py :

```
from ctypes import *
from  pythonWrapper import *
count =0
ret = dvDeviceGet(None, count)
print (count)
```

The output ret is getting successful but count value is still 0 but inside c function it is being changed say 2. but in python variable it is still 0.

Can someone point my mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`byref(c_int(count))` creates a new `c_int` and passes a pointer to *that*. `count` is unaffected. `count` is an ordinary Python int, not a C int or a wrapper object for a C int.

Comment: So i have to create c_int in test.py? Isnt there any way to assign c_int object value to python int? Actullay i tried to do count = c.value where is separate object but this count is updated here in pythonwrapper.py but not reflecting again in test.py

Comment: I got it . I guess returning count will suffice

Comment: yeah it worked for me i created new c_int object and returning this will update the value of count

Answer (score 0):

A little refactoring:

```
_obj = cdll.LoadLibrary(./sharedObj.so)

# Only need to do this once, not every time inside the function
_obj.wrappedAPI.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(structwrapList),ctypes.POINTER(c_int)]
_obj.wrappedAPI.restype = ctypes.c_int # Needs to be a ctypes type.

def wrappedAPI(structwrapList,count):
    if not structwrapList:
        structwrapList = structwrap()
    c_count = ctypes.c_int(count) # Create a ctypes type to pass by reference
    ret = _obj.orgAPI(byref(structwrapList),ctypes.byref(c_count))
    return ret,c_count.value
```

Call with:

```
ret,count = dvDeviceGet(None, count)
```